# Dynamically class instantiation with non default constructor

Tags: java, reflection, jruby

I am attempting to dynamically instantiate a java class, given the absolute path to a jar file and the class name. Concretely this java class I am trying to instantiate:

```
public Tool(String[] args) {
   this.args = args;
   errMgr = new ErrorManager(this);
   errMgr.setFormat(msgFormat);
   handleArgs();
}
```

I have been trying the following:

```
require 'java';
java_import 'java.io.File';
java_import 'java.net.URL';
java_import 'java.net.URLClassLoader';


class JarLoader
    def self.load_class(p_jar_path, p_class_name, p_args)
        # p_jar_path: absolute path to jat 
        l_jar_url = File.new(p_jar_path).toURL;
        l_url_arr = Array[l_jar_url].to_java(java.net.URL);
        l_class_loader = JavaNet::URLClassLoader.new(l_url_arr);
        # p_class_name: name of the class
        l_class_type = l_class_loader.loadClass(p_class_name);
        # Get the right constructor
        l_constructor = l_class_type.getConstructor(Array(String).to_java.class);
        return l_constructor.newInstance(p_args.to_java(:string));
    end
end
```

I get the error

```
Java::JavaLang::NoSuchMethodException: org.antlr.v4.Tool.<init>([Ljava.lang.Object;)
```

Somehow the parameter to the constructor ends up being of the wrong type.
I am using java jdk 1.5 (because I need to work with a oracle 11g db) and jruby 1.7.1.

I am at my wits end with this one. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where do you get the error? What if you use a java string when you get the ctor instead of a ruby string?

Comment: Hi Dave, thank you for calling :) The error occurs when I am trying to fetch the right constructor `l_constructor = l_class_type.getConstructor(Array(String).to_java.class);`.

Comment: Hi Dave, this is working 
'l_constructor = l_class_type.getConstructor(l_args.to_java(:string).class)'. I am getting the right constructor back. 'l_constructor.to_s' returns "public org.antlr.v4.Tool(java.lang.String[])". Calling this constructor  'l_constructor.newInstance(l_args.to_java(:string)) fails with an IllegalArgumentEXception though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a (Java) String array to `get_declared_constructor` to retrieve the right constructor, and then pass that array as an object when calling `newInstance`:

```
# Get the right constructor
l_constructor = l_class_type.get_declared_constructor(p_args.to_java(:string).java_class)
return l_constructor.new_instance(p_args.to_java(:string).to_java_object)
```

Comment: Salut Sébastien, thank you for your answer. It is working correcly now. I was missing the call to 'to_java_object'.

Comment: Thank you your help :)
Wolfgang Hämmer

Comment: @wolfganghämmer No prob, it was a tricky one to get to work, even in Java!